# Xcode not recognizing updated Pod Libraries as Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I updated Xcode today to Xcode 8 and was asked to convert my code into swift 3, which I did. I also opened up my pod file and updated my 2 libraries, Alamofire and CVCalendar view to the their newest Swift 3.0 supported versions. However, there are still some odd errors that are preventing me from building the app.I am getting errors like

```
 Module file was created by an older version of the compiler; rebuild 'Alamofire' and try again: [Path to Module]

Command /usr/bin/ditto failed with exit code 1

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

 Failed to read Info.plist of app Path/Xcode/DerivedData/BRGO-cmhsxuafeewtybbrnrbtuymvljcp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/BRGO.app (Couldn't load Info dictionary for <DVTFilePath:0x7fb86eed0bb0:'/Users/Praveen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BRGO-cmhsxuafeewtybbrnrbtuymvljcp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/BRGO.app'>)
```

My app compiled perfectly fine before updating to Xcode 8.0. Now I am receiving these errors and i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using cocoa pods 1.1.0 try updating it:

```
[sudo] gem install cocoapods --pre
```

Them change your podfile to have the newest version of Alamofire:

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
```

Run `pod install` again.

And remove the DerivedData from simulator by going to simulator -> Reset contents and settings.